# Jquery UI sortable has image among sort item

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-ui

[image]

I have a sortable list like the above image, each sortable block has a icon between them.

The current code in jquery UI sortable is like this:

```
    if (count($track_list) > 0) {
        echo "<ul class='sortable_panel'>";
            foreach ($track_list as $key => $video) {
                ?>
                <li class="video_bar">
                 .....
                </li>
                <?php
                if ($key != count($track_list) - 1) {
                    echo "<div style='text-align:center;'><i class='fa fa-link icon-flipped'></i></div>";
                }
            }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
```

Javascript:

```
$('.sortable_panel').sortable();
```

The problem is , how to

1) make the icon not sortable

2) if the first item is drag to last item, how to make the second item become the first item and above the icon?

Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to have a JS fiddle (or some alternative) for this. It's hard to say what's happening, especially without seeing the actual call to jQuery UI's sortable method.

Comment: thanks for reply. for javascript it is just calling the sortable, sure will have js fiddle later

Comment: Ok, the reason I ask is that sortable has an option called items. Using that you can specify which items inside your container should be sortable. http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-items